# $\mathbf{Rng}$ is not a subcategory of $\mathbf{Ab}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I read in the book [**Categories and functors** (Pareigis)](https://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/7244/1/7244.pdf) that the category of rings **Rng** is not a subcategory of the category of abelian groups **Ab**.

I didn't understand the argument the author used: although each ring is an abelian group, the underlying structures of abelian group may coincide hence $\textrm{Obj}(\mathbf{Rng})\subseteq \textrm{Obj}(\mathbf{Ab})$ does not hold.

Of course the underlying structure of abelian groups may coincide even if the rings are different but I didn't understand why this imply rings are not a subcategory of abelian groups.

Comment: $S$ being a subcategory of $C$ means - among other things - that one has an injective functional class $\operatorname{Ob}(S) \to \operatorname{Ob}(C)$. Forgetting multiplication is not injective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case I agree, but it seems the author didn't follow precisely his definition of subcategory. By the way, where can I read about this functional class stuff?

Comment: @DanielFischer: But if the object part of the injective functional doesn't have to be verbatim identity, then we can just remember the multiplication within the elements and map $(R,{+},{\cdot})$ to $(\{\cdot\}\times R,\hat +)$ where $(\cdot,a)\hat+(\cdot,b)=(\cdot,a+b)$...

Comment: Are you sure the question isn't whether there is an embedding of $Rng$ in $Ab$ ? As it is, you're talking about whether the forgetful functor is a strict embedding, which is just obviously not true and not very interesting.

Comment: Would you mind repeating Pareigis' definition of subcategory, then?

Comment: Well, he states in the book Rng is not a subcategory of Ab so I guess the question is right the way it is.

Comment: Good point @Henning. But if one requires the object "mapping" to be the identity, can there be any nontrivial subcategories at all?

Comment: @DanielFischer **Ab** as a subcategory of **Grp**, perhaps

Comment: I think Daniel Fischer explained exactly what Paregis meant: since two rings can have the same additive group but different multiplications, the map from Ob(Rng) to Ob(Ab) is not injective, so you cannot regard Ob(Rng) as a subset of Ob(Ab).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is meant in the book is that the forgetful functor $U : \mathsf{Rng} \to \mathsf{Ab}$ does not make $\mathsf{Rng}$ into a subcategory of $\mathsf{Ab}$, because two different rngs may have the same underlying abelian group. For example, consider $\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual operations, and the same $\mathbb{Z}$ but where $x \cdot y = 0$ for all $x$ and $y$. So $U$ is not an injection of objects, let alone an embedding of categories.

Now it *is* true that, even then, there could possibly be another functor $F : \mathsf{Rng} \to \mathsf{Ab}$ that makes $\mathsf{Rng}$ into a subcategory of $\mathsf{Ab}$, but this isn't what the author meant (in all likelihood). Here is what he wrote:

> The corresponding abelian groups of two rings may coincide even if the
>   rings do not coincide. The multiplication may be defined differently.

Which matches the explanation in the first paragraph. Finding a functor $F : \mathsf{Rng} \to \mathsf{Ab}$ that induces an injection on objects and hom-sets would be a harder question.